# Error in svd(X, nu = 0L) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, dataframe, validation, data-science, linear-programming

I am currentry working with some kind of data analysis by R studio.
My project code is something like this:

```
library(Momocs)
library(geomorph)

CharredCoords <- list.files("C:\\Users\\grain_coords_mod", full.names = TRUE)
CharredFrame <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\data_matrix_new_mod.csv", header = TRUE)
CharredTxt <- import_txt(CharredCoords, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
CharredOut <- Out(CharredTxt, fac=CharredFrame)
CharredOut1 <-coo_scale (CharredOut)
CharredOut.l <- filter(CharredOut1, View == "l")
CharredOut.d <- filter(CharredOut1, View == "d")
CharredOut.l.efour <- efourier(CharredOut.l, nb.h=8, norm = FALSE, start = TRUE)
CharredOut.d.efour <- efourier(CharredOut.d, nb.h=8, norm = FALSE, start = TRUE)
```

Till its okay... Then after when I execute the following line, error occurs

```
CharredOut.l %>% chop(~View) %>% lapply(efourier,nb.h=8, norm = FALSE, start = FALSE) %>% combine %>% LDA ('G_Variety', scale=FALSE, center= TRUE)
```

Output: Error in svd(X, nu = 0L) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : variables are collinear

---

Looking for some suggestion like what I suppose to do or check to solve that isuue.
Thanks in advance.`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2TMa.png)

Code should be render for further ploting procedure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since we can't access `data_matrix_new_mod.csv`, can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing your data using `dput()` or by using an example dataset?

Comment: @jrcalabrese Okay, should I provide my data here for better understanding?
If yes then there you go (It's a sample data)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EoklXZePonE5-kVbjhyh2i3iMj1PUBua/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19TqmWYjEAzpB-YsGMHKze_G_i2AEEP44?usp=share_link